# External offset store with the debezium embedded connector

Tags: amazon-web-services, debezium

My team is building a CDC service with the Debezium embedded connector. For the offset storage we're thinking about using S3/DynamoDB. Just wondering if anyone here has written something similar to externalize the offset store and what they chose and why they chose that.

Comment: Which DB system are you connecting to?

Answer (score 1):

We have a Postgres DB as source. Change Data Capture (CDC) is implemented by the Postgres itself (done by the extension [pglogical](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical)). This CDC subsystem of Postgres is responsible for offset management. The CDC subsytem will maintain a list of CDC clients (aka slots). So if your client creates a CDC connection the DB will start from the point where that client disconnected before (on the same slot). A new client will create a new slot and start receiving only the CDC records created from that point in time on. So there is no need for us to remember the offsets.

Answer (score 1):

Had this challenge recently. You can write a custom class that implements `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore` or extend `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.MemoryOffsetBackingStore`.
Subsequently ensure "offset.storage" config is set to the fully-qualified class name

Please see a sample below using redis (maybe not in production) as a backing store to give you an idea how this can work.

```
package com.sample.cdc.offsetbackingstore

import com.sample.cdc.service.RedisManager
import org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException
import org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig
import org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.MemoryOffsetBackingStore
import java.io.IOException
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.util.concurrent.Callable
import java.util.concurrent.Future


class RedisOffsetBackingStore : MemoryOffsetBackingStore() {
    lateinit var redisManager : RedisManager
    lateinit var redisHost : String
    lateinit var redisPort : String

    override fun configure(config: WorkerConfig?) {
        super.configure(config) 
        
        redisHost = config?.getString("custom.config.redis.host")
        redisPort = config?.getString("custom.config.redis.port") 
    }

    // Called by Debezium Engine at some point
    override fun start() {
        super.start()
        println("Initializing redis manager...")
        redisManager = RedisManager(redisHost, redisPort)
    }
    
    // Called by Debezium Engine during graceful shutdown
    override fun stop() {
        super.stop()
        println("Disposing redis client resources...")
        if(this::redisManager.isInitialized)
            redisManager.dispose()
    }
 
    // Called by DebeziumEngine OffsetReader to read Offset
    override fun get(keys: MutableCollection<ByteBuffer>?): Future<MutableMap<ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer?>> {
        if(data.isNotEmpty())
            return super.get(keys)
        return executor.submit(Callable<MutableMap<ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer?>> {
            val result: MutableMap<ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer?> = HashMap()
            keys?.forEach {
                val offsetKey = String(it.array())
                val offsetValue = redisManager.get(offsetKey)
                if(offsetValue.isNotEmpty()){
                    val buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(offsetValue.toByteArray())
                    result[it] = buffer
                    data[it] = buffer
                }
            }
            result
        })
    }
    
    // Invoked by set() in MemoryOffsetBackingStore class to persist Offset  
    // during commit or graceful shutdown
    override fun save() {
        try {
            for ((key, value) in data) {
                val offsetKey = String(key!!.array())
                val offsetValue = String(value!!.array())
                redisManager.save(offsetKey, offsetValue)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw ConnectException(e)
        }
    }
}

//Ensure the below config setting is set in DebeziumConfig
//"offset.storage":"com.sample.cdc.offsetbackingstore.RedisOffsetBackingStore",
//"custom.config.redis.host": "localhost"
//"custom.config.redis.port": "6379"
```

Note: In case of multiple standalone embedded debezium services (for reliabilty and fault tolerance) with a custom offset backing store, you'll have to provide a way to handle offset race condition, and event deduplication.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependency for debezium-redis which you can use now,
with dependency-

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.debezium</groupId>
<artifactId>debezium-storage-redis</artifactId>
<version>${debezium.redis.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

see:- https://debezium.io/blog/2022/11/10/debezium-2-1-alpha1-released/

For configurations- https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/operations/debezium-server.html#debezium-source-configuration-properties

Sample Demo:-
https://github.com/HimanshBhatnagar/spring-boot-debezium